# Electromagnet creates loud noises when changing voltage

Tags: arduino, voltage, electromagnetism

for a project I'm using a electromagnet (currently this: https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/152311638782) to dynamically pull an object based on the value coming from a potentiometer.
In a nutshell: the potentiometer's value is controlling the voltage applied to the electromagnet.

The problem that arises is that, when changing the voltage (and sometimes without changing it) the magnet produces quite annoying noises. Is this to do with the quality of the magnet? Or is this something that can't be prevented because of the nature of how they're built?

Thank you!

---

Hi guys, thank you. Here is an image of circuit:

[image: image of circuit]

(not sure if I drew the transistor correctly) and a [video of the sound](https://youtu.be/9z0_H-u8p0A) – thank you and sorry for being so unspecific.

Comment: Can you be any more unspecific?

Comment: Show schematic. Descibe noises.

Comment: please be more specific. Schematic will be helpful!

Comment: It can't possibly work with the transistor like that!

Comment: Hello Leon. I just realised that I'm using a MOSFET, not an transistor. Could that be the problem because I read it has a built in capacitor?

Comment: That whining noise? If so, something is generating high frequencies instead of, or as well as, DC

Comment: Redraw a correct schematic. Show your voltage source too.

Comment: Why are you using a BJT or MOSFET in the first place? Just for driving the magnet, or do you mean to toggle the voltage on/off somehow?

Comment: Hey @Lundin – I need to control the strength of it constantly. And not only on/off but smooth, that's why I'm using a transistor. Even though the more i research the more I think MOFSET might not be the right thing to use here?

Answer (score 1):

**First my assumptions**; I can't verify the quality of that particular electromagnet but I can elaborate on the inherent vibration on an electro magnet with a changing power supply.

**Now my argument**; An electro magnet will hum or vibrate when the source voltage is not pure DC. The changing magnetic field can create higher frequency hums, which is my guess as to what you are hearing. The truth is that if you change the DC input on the magnet you will get humming while the change occurs. So as you are sitting there cranking your potentiometer dial you are actually creating the hums. Of course you may also get some leakage and ripples based on the various components of the circuit that may create a non-ideal DC signal to the electromagnet.

**So on to the solution**; I would run a test on your magnet to see if it hums at the battery voltage directly (please check ratings to ensure it doesn't blow up, maybe try a smaller battery if you are not sure). If you hear a humming I would then conclude it is most likely the magnet.

If you do not hear a humming then the issue is with the changing DC voltage in your circuit. You can add filtering elements such as a capacitor to help smooth the signal but by using a potentiometer to change the signal you are inherently creating a hum.

Anyway, just my two cents, if I were you I'd fiddle around with filtering or perhaps the speed at which the potentiometer voltage changes and such.

I wish you the best!

Comment: Hey @Commanderson – I tried it with a battery attached. There is no noise at all. So I tried to use a capacitor. But as soon as I add the capacitor even the Potentiometer readings go crazy. These are the schematics how i'm doing it. ![circuit](http://udiocollective.com/180214-transistor-capacitor-scheme_schem.png) – thank you so much!

Comment: Apologies, but I am unsure why you have chosen to connect the electromagnet to Vin. Vin is an input power pin for arduino's is it not? Furthermore, I don't not believe arduino's come with build in digital to analog converters so you have to output to a digital pin. Here is a link to clarify what I am asking, can you please try something closer to example 2 in this [link](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/projects/using-the-arduinos-analog-io/). Mind you the digital pin will still be very poor DC since it is Pulse Width Modulated. I would suggest trying this first and then sizing the capacitor.

Comment: thanks so much for your help. If a power supply (12v) is plugged into the arduino, the Vin will provide that. I am using the Vin to power the magnet and the Transistor to control the amount of power. The transistor I am controlling with Digital Pin 10, which is a PWM pin. I managed to make repair the potentiometer bad readings. Now, when attaching a big capacitor (220µF), the magnet becomes crazy strong + there is no noise at all! Which is great. When I add a tiny capacitor, the magnet is weaker. yet I don't understand why the capacitor can change the strength of the magnet.

Comment: Generally speaking, the electromagnet could not filter out as much as the cap could (as you heard from the humming). This in turn reduced the average DC voltage on the electromagnet and made it weaker. Had you placed the same voltage using a battery you would get it to behave stronger than with the cap or without.

Answer (score 0):

You have two steel plates held together with what appear to be rubber bands, I assume for the weight? The sound is likely the magnetostriction of the steel plates and their vibration against one another. Remove one plate and see if it goes away. If so, change to using one larger plate instead of two smaller ones, or weld them together (although that might not work totally)